# Замена двоеточие на точку в строке метки времени

Tags: строки, datetime, powershell

Имеется строковый массив с метками времени в формате "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:fff". Требуется заменить двоеточие на точку перед миллисекундами, чтобы получилось "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff".

Пробовал сделать так:

```
$TimeStr = "2023-01-16 08:00:00:000"
$TimeStr = $TimeStr.replace("00:000", "00.000")
```

В результате получаю строку "00:00.0". Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать правильно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Один из вариантов - найти последнее двоеточие, вырезать подстроки слева и справа и соединить их через точку

```
$TimeStr = "2023-01-16 08:00:00:000"
$pos = $TimeStr.LastIndexOf(':')
$TimeStr = $TimeStr.Substring(0,$pos-1)+"."+$TimeStr.Substring($pos+1)
$TimeStr
```

Или оператором замены с помощью регулярного выражения:

```
$TimeStr = "2023-01-16 08:00:00:000"
$TimeStr = $TimeStr -replace ':(\d+)$','.$1'
$TimeStr
```

```
2023-01-16 08:00:0.000
```

Comment: Ваш код работает правильно, получаю метки в нужном формате. Дальше в моём коде эти метки вставляются в столбец excel-листа, и дальше этот лист преобразуется в txt с помощью .SaveAs($tmp,42). Так вот в этом .txt файле метки всё равно попадают некорректные, как у меня в примере. Тогда как метки с двоеточием перед fff в .txt-файле остаются корректными  Подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить?

Answer (score 0):

```
'2023-01-16 08:00:00:000' -replace ':(?=\d{1,3}$)', '.'
```

> 2023-01-16 08:00:00.000